# Ruby/Chipmunk tutorial(s)

Tags: ruby, physics, chipmunk

I can't seem to find any tutorials on how to use Chipmunk from Ruby, only [this one](https://github.com/jlnr/gosu/wiki/Ruby-Chipmunk-Integration). I'd prefer something else because it only shows how to use it for a top-down view, and I want a side view, so things fall towards the bottom of the screen. I'd like a tutorial too; not the official Ruby/Chipmunk docs. Anywhere I can find such a thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about ruby bindings for chipmunk? https://github.com/beoran/chipmunk There is a demo and specs.